# Close threads when invoked by user

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple WinForms app that is to serve as a server for multiple TelNet clients. When each one of these clients connects then a new thread is created. This is all working fine. However, I haven't found a suitable way to close these threads when I need to. 
All the examples I have found online use `Thread.Abort` (which I know is a bad idea) or deal with threads created from the same class, which isn't what I need to do.

This is a simplified version of my classes:

Main UI class:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _listener = new TelNetListener(_deviceConnection);
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // NEED TO SIGNAL Listener and all Client threads to stop here.
}
```

Listener class (thread created from Main UI class):

```
public TelNetListener(DeviceConnection deviceConnection)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => TelNetListenerStart(deviceConnection));
    thread.Start();
}

private void TelNetListenerStart(DeviceConnection deviceConnection)
{
    Socket listener;
    listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    listener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
    listener.Listen(100);

    _allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    while (true)
    {
        _allDone.Reset();
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listener);
        _allDone.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void AcceptCallBack()
{
    telNetClient = new TelNetClient(clientSocket, string.Format("ACTN{0}",
        _clientCounter.ToString("D4")));
}
```

Client class (thread created from Listener class):

```
public TelNetClient(Socket socket, string clientName)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => TelNetClientStart(socket, clientName));
    thread.Start();
}

private void TelNetClientStart(Socket socket, string clientName)
{
    DeviceConnection deviceConnection = new DeviceConnection();

    this.ClientName = clientName;
    this.State = new StateObject();
    this.State.WorkSocket = socket;

    Send(this.State, "Welcome...");

    this.State.WorkSocket.BeginReceive(this.State.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), this.State);
}
```

Bare in mind there is a fair amount of code missing, so if there are undeclared variables or anything like that, just ignore them. I just didn't want to put in loads of irrelevant code.

I have seen examples using a `ManualResetEvent` which seems to be what I need to do, but I'm not sure where to place it so that all the threads will work off it. Maybe I need 2, one for the `Main` class to signal the `Listener` class and from there another to signal all the `Client` classes?

Could anyone help me with this please as it is pretty much the last part of the infrastructure needed for this project.

If you need any more information I will try and provide it.

Comment: Have youconsidered rewriting that part and getting ridof all the threads and follow best practices to use a sockte and a thread pool and then SELECT The sockets with new data? Makes things a lot easier.

Comment: If you're using asyc methods everywhere anyway then why do you need the extra threads?

Comment: A proper Telnet server does not terminate until all clients have disconnected.  Not much point in implementing a feature that is so disruptive to anybody that would want to use your server.  Or starting a thread only to call BeginReceive().

Comment: @TomTom Do you have any examples of this? I came onto this project part way through, so the basics of the TelNet stuff was already done. I don't understand TelNet too much so I just ran with what I had.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that it shouldn't terminate until all clients have disconnected, but it is a requirement for the project. Also if the program needs to close while a device is connected (for example left in a drawer somewhere), the option is required so I don't have loads of extra threads floating around.

Comment: You are going to pull the plug on these clients, interrupting their service instantly.  Why would you care that this is done in a "clean" way?  The outcome will be the same.  The Thread.IsBackground property exists to allow the CLR to be rude about it.  Setting it to *true* gets the CLR to pull the plug without your help.  Don't use threads.

Comment: Who is setting the _allDone event? It looks like you start an async IO, then immediately wait for completion. That makes no sense. Use the synchronous API directly. If you want to abort communication, Shutdown or Close the socket. Outstanding IOs will be terminated.

Comment: @usr The _allDone event is not really being used, that was already there when I inherited the project. That's why I thought I should be using it, but I'm not sure how in this situation. In fact I'm thinking that the whole thing seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code:

```
while (true)
    {
        _allDone.Reset();
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listener);
        _allDone.WaitOne();
    }
```

with some variable in your class which you can set.

```
while (this.Work)
    {
        _allDone.Reset();
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), listener);
        _allDone.WaitOne();
    }
```

When you want to stop a listener you simply set the Work property to false.

Comment: If you go that route, make sure this.Work is marked as volatile

Comment: That seems lie some of the examples I have seen, however that would only effect the Listener thread, what about all of the Client threads?